# Why cannot return params from url nodejs

Tags: node.js

Here my server code

```
var express = require("express");
var isAuthen = require('./middleware/authorize')
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var order_process = require('./routes/order-process');
app.use('/order',isAuthen, order_process);
```

and here order_process code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../models/database');

router.get('/', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    try {
        console.log(req.params);
}catch(err){
console.log(err);
}
module.exports = router;

http://localhost:3000/order/2
```

as i know that url should return number 2 ??
i dont know why it cannot return ?

should return correct params from url

Comment: Did you check the variables in req.params in debug mode?

Comment: Hi @Wyck i tried but it return cannot Get /order ? am i wrong some where ?

Comment: hi @comnerd23 i dont get it can show write some more detail ?

Comment: oh wait I see it's a router.  try `router.get('/:page'`...

Comment: Hi @Wyck it weird i changed to `router.get('/:page')` and file server `app.use('/order/:page')` as well still return cannot Get /order

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion of my first comment. I think `app.use('/order'` but `router.get('/:page'`

Comment: Hi @Wyck sorry for disapointed you but i have tested your solution before but still return Cannot get it weird ...

Comment: You haven't shown how you set up your router.

Comment: hi @Wyck i just updated my post pls help me check it

Comment: Post **complete minimal** code.  There are necessary things like `module.exports = router` that are missing.  I just tried your code (filling in the blanks with guesswork) and it works fine if you set the route to `/:page`.  So the problem is in code that you are not showing.

Comment: Hi @Wyck file work without add /:page so weird ..

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to get the params from a route:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();

app.use('/order', router);

router.get('/:page', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`You are viewing page ${req.params.page}`);
});

const server = app.listen(8000);
```

Then go to `http://localhost:8000/order/2` and you should see it say:

> You are viewing page 2